# passing parameters using link_to in haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
%tbody
  - @accounts.each do |account|
    %tr
      %td= link_to account['id'],show_path,{:id => account['id']}
      %td= account['name']
      %td= account['description']
      %td= account['created']
```

The above is just a snippet from a haml file and in my controller i have the following:

```
def show 
  # If a system account already exists in session, it was found from a search with the account id
  # Otherwise, this is a new search for a system account by the given id
  @account = session[:account]
  if @account.nil?
    Rails.logger.debug { "Querying for the account with id: #{params[:id]}" }
    response = query_account(CGI.escape(params[:id]))
    @account = JSON.parse(response.body)
  end
end
```

The route(show_path) is /system_accounts/:id

how do i pass the parameter id to the controller and link  /system_accounts/23 if the id is 23 for eg: .

Comment: Where's the link leading to? Is it a accounts#show?

Comment: @Niko Efimov yeah so doing rake routes:  system_account GET    /system_accounts/:id(.:format)      system_accounts#show

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will link to the correct show page for the account:

```
= link_to account.id, account
```

You can always explicitly add any additional parameters to the path:

```
= link_to account.id, account_path(:id => account.id, :foo => "bar")
```

Comment: I am sure you meant account['id'] and yeah it worked. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: It's more common to use object.param rather than object['param'], that's why I wrote it that way. Glad it helped!